# Is allowing www-data to execute commands without a password safe?

Tags: php, security, terminal, sudo

I need to know if allowing www-data to execute sudo commands without a password is safe?

I am using it to execute terminal commands from a php script but this isn't suitable for our live production servers?

here is the sudoers file.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

here is an example of a command I'm trying to run to an external remote server.
I'm using ssh2_exec to run this.

```
sudo service apache2 status;sudo service mysql status;sudo service mongod status
```

If not, is there a better way around being able to do this?

Comment: No, it is probably not safe at all. If you do this there is a high probability that visitors of your web site may influence the execution of privileged actions, if not controlling them completely. And nobody wants this. Even if you try to avoid this by a careful design of your php code, you will be victim of bugs in your own code, if the php module or in any other involved component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This essentially makes your web server a prime vector for attacks on a site. If someone can find a way to upload any sort of code, or there's ever a point in future where you `shell_exec` with a user variable string, people can execute privileged arbitrary code on your site.

This is not suitable for publicly accessible servers.

A better way to do this would be to write a program on your system which runs in `crontab` and prints these values to a flat file, then open that file in PHP.

e.g

```
#!/bin/bash

service apache2 status
service mysql status
service mongod status
```

Add this to root user cron with `sudo crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /path/to/script > /home/my-user/file
```

You might need to also make the file global readable (after it's created); it's just a status so probably safe:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/my-user/file
```

Then in PHP

```
<?php

$status = file_get_contents('/home/my-user/file');
echo $status;
```

Comment: I've changed the script to handle multiple outputs; at which point it makes more sense to pass the output to a file in the crontab.

Comment: Thank you M1ke, the only problem is the PHP script is ran on a Raspberry Pi and checks on 3 remote servers.

Comment: Do you have access to the remote servers? You can make that file accessible through a web root, and just run the cron there.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a cron job would solve the issue in your case.
But what if you don't want it as a cron job, or what if you had to pass dynamic positional arguments while executing the script ?

So an efficient solution for this is to put your code in a .sh file as you did.

But instead of doing

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Do this

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script.sh
```

This will make sure that www-data has elevated privileges only for that particular script and not anything else. This can be safely used on your production servers as www-data can't run any other script without root permission.

I found this answer helpful at https://anto.online/code/how-to-run-php-script-root/